# Linux command history for multiple sessions by root user

Tags: linux

We have multiple guys logged in as root at the same time. How can I  view their command history during login or after terminating their session.

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

I merge them in the configuration file using:

```
shopt -s histappend
```

This is usually enough for me to see session info after the logout (by examining the history file). I also timestamp with:

```
export HISTTIMEFORMAT='%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S  '
```

Some people also set the history to reload and popular after each command. I don't, but this is the popular recipe for that:

```
# Save and reload the history after each command finishes
export PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -c; history -r; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

All of this ends up in a /etc/bashrc or a snippet in /etc/profile.d/

Comment: "All of this ends up in a /etc/bashrc or a snippet in /etc/profile.d/" U mean I should put "shopt -s histappened" in bashrc as well?

Comment: if you want to, yes.